# Create alias with oh my zsh

Tags: zsh

Bit confused here, within the ~/.zshrc file I have specified the following:

```
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias burp="java -jar -server -Xms1048m -Xmx2G -XX:-DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseT$
alias htb="openvpn /root/example.ovpn"
alias webgoat="java -jar /root/webgoat-container-7.0-SNAPSHOT-war-exec.jar"
alias cl="clear"
```

However whenever i try to run any, even cl i receive:

```
zsh: command not found: cl
```

I know there is many many posts about this subject but as far as I can tell I have followed the configuration correctly. Would really appreciate if someone can point out where i've gone wrong.

Thanks!

Also not sure if its relevant but i'm running on Kali Linux.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Kali Linux is not supported here… However, have you tried to fix your file by putting a closing double quote (`"`) at the end of the `alias burp` line?

Comment: also remeber to type `source ~/.zshrc`. changes are not loaded automatically, you have to sort-of "export" them.

Answer (score 3):

```
alias burp="java -jar -server -Xms1048m -Xmx2G -XX:-DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseT$
```

The alias "burp" does not have a closing quote mark at the end. So the all aliases below this line in your RC file will throw this error.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!